# What is the probability distribution of linear formula?

Tags: probability, distributions

What is the distribution name when probability values have a linear increasing of the form:

$p(i)= \frac{2}{N(N+1)}i;  0 \leq i \leq N $

Comment: While there are [triangular probability distributions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Triangular_distribution), I do not think the function you supplied is a probability distribution over the support $0\dots N$, because the area under its curve does not equal 1.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is a valid distribution if $i$ is integer, otherwise it isn't as @Alexis points out. When integer, if we sum over all possibilities, we get $1$:
$$\sum_{i=1}^N{\frac{2}{N(N+1)}}i=\frac{2}{N(N+1)}\sum_{i=1}^N{}i=\frac{2}{N(N+1)}\frac{N(N+1)}{2}=1$$
Wikipedia entry for [List of Probability Distributions](https://www.wikiwand.com/en/List_of_probability_distributions) doesn't associate this with a special name, however it is being [used](https://www.cl.cam.ac.uk/teaching/2003/Probability/prob03.pdf) in some sources as *Discrete Triangular Distribution*, although the name has also been [used](https://learnandteachstatistics.files.wordpress.com/2013/07/notes-on-triangle-distributions.pdf) to describe the probability distribution of two dice, in which the distribution is symmetric around a mean. As [continuous case](https://www.wikiwand.com/en/Triangular_distribution) refers generally to asymmetric version of the triangle shape (which also includes $b=c$, i.e. *right* triangle), the discrete version can also do this, which makes the name *valid* practically.

Comment: (+1) for mentioning applications. The continuous version is $\mathsf{Beta}(2,1).$

Answer (score 2):

I think you intend this to be a *discrete* distribution.

If $N=5$ you have $P(X = i) = \frac{2i}{30} = \frac{i}{15}.$ Notice that, whatever $N$ you choose, $P(X = 0) = 0.$

You need to check that the probabilities add to $1:$ that is, $\sum_{i=0}^{5} P(X = i) = 1.$
For that, you might want to look at [this Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/1_%2B_2_%2B_3_%2B_4_%2B_%E2%8B%AF).

Here is a plot of the PDF (or PMF) of this distribution.

[image]